# load local host url from config file in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails application in which I am consuming a REST API method. For testing purpose, I am using like

```
RestClient.post "http://localhost:3000/book/#{book_name}/search"
```

I want a method that returns the base route (`http://localhost:3000`), so what is the best method to do it in rails.

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html

```
URI is a module providing classes to handle Uniform Resource Identifiers
```

Sample:

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI("http://foo.com/posts?id=30&limit=5#time=1305298413")
#=> #<URI::HTTP:0x00000000b14880
      URL:http://foo.com/posts?id=30&limit=5#time=1305298413>
uri.scheme
#=> "http"
uri.host
#=> "foo.com"
```